# STPCustomerContext no longer declares selectDefaultCustomerSource

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

After upgrading my stripe SDK to the latest version, Stripe 19.4.0 (was 15.0.1), STP Customer Context no longer seems to declare the function "selectDefaultCustomerSource".

Unfortunately I am unable to go back to previous version as xcode 11.4 has breaking changes for previous stripe versions.

So my question is how do i select default customer source with the new SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe's iOS SDK has defaulted its pre-built components (like STPCustomerContext) to leveraging PaymentMethods, the modern abstraction for tokens over the )now legacy) Tokens/Cards/Sources, since v16.0.0.

PaymentMethods have no concept of a "default" any more, you can attach multiple PaymentMethods to a Customer but they don't specify a default. STPCustomerContext supports attaching the PaymentMethod to the Customer.

There is a way to specify "default for Invoices and Subscriptions only" (not applicable for one-time payments), which is a server-side request to update a Customer object's `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method, so you would make this request on your backend (the iOS SDK doesn't support this currently)

Comment: Wait so they took away functionality? That's insane.

Comment: that functionality was deprecated, as the Sources/Tokens/Cards API is now legacy. You can still use that older integration but you'll have to use a Stripe iOS SDK version before v16.0.0 (which I understand you can't do in this scenario). I'd just recommend integrating against PaymentMethods, as it future proofs your integration and is the recommended path forward